# How to solve differential equation involving dot product of vectors?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

I'm trying to find the position of the midpoint of the rear axis of a vehicle (Q), given the position of the midpoint of the front axis of the vehicle (P). I'm looking at the following paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222417459_Mathematical_models_for_motion_of_the_rear_ends_of_vehicles

I understand how they derived the following equation on page 4:

$$\dot{B}=\left(\frac{\dot{P}\cdot B}{L^2}\right)B-\dot{P}$$

Where $B$ is the vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$, $P$ is the position vector of point P at time $t$, and $L$ is the distance between P and Q, and is a constant.

My question is: how do you solve the equation to find $B$ in terms of $P$ and/or $L$?

I have considered making $e^{\int\left(\frac{\dot{P}\cdot B}{L^2}\right)B-\dot{P}}$ the integrating factor. However, I'm not sure this works, as $B$ is present in it. Furthermore, I'm unsure how to approach the multiplication of $B$ by a scalar, which is a function of the dot product of two vectors.

Comment: Since B is just a vector, the multiplication by a scalar means simply that every component of vector is multiplied by that scalar, thus you can view like a kind of stretching or shortening of a vector

Comment: @TheCoolDrop Thank you. Despite everything within the brackets evaluating to a value, I assume we cannot treat it as a constant when deriving/integrating?

Comment: I have honestly very limited knowledge about differential equations in general, but I assume that you can not treat it like a constant when integrating, because if you view all of the variables as time dependent ( that is since P is time dependent, then B must also be time dependent, unless Q is time dependent in some very specific fashion relative to P, as to make B constant which is not case here),  then their product is also time-dependant, thus can not be treated as constant